# SQL Server 2008 Sum function not returning rows with no data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, null, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to write a report that is the product of two tables. In short, there is an `Office` table and a `Report` table. I want to return all offices, regardless if there are any reports, and a sum of the line counts from the `Reports` table.

My report looks like the following:

```
SELECT 
    o.NAME,
    SUM(rpt.transcriptionlinecount) AS 'Total Lines'
FROM
    office AS o
LEFT JOIN 
    RptLineCountInfo AS rpt ON rpt.officeID = o.officeID
WHERE  
    rpt.finishedTime BETWEEN startDate AND endDate + 1
    AND rpt.officeID = CASE
                         WHEN officeID IS NULL THEN rpt.officeID
                         ELSE officeID
                       END
    AND (rpt.dictationStatus != 'd'
         AND rpt.dictationstatus != 'q')
    AND rpt.officeID != '2'
     OR rpt.transcriptionLineCount IS NULL
GROUP BY 
    o.[name]
ORDER BY 
    o.[name];
```

I do have some additional information in the where clause, such as report status and date range. The issue I have is that if I query the `Office` table, there should are 250 results. With my query above only 101 results are returned. There were zero reports for the remaining 149 offices during this time frame, but I would still like them to appear on the report either with a 0 or a Null.  Any suggestions on on how to achieve this would be great.

Comment: Use a `left join` (and put `office` first.  You'll need to show the whole query for a more complete answer.

Comment: The left join worked a bit.  The results are up to 130 now.  Below is the full query after your suggestion.

Comment: Below is the full query after your suggestion (took out the declared variables because of character limit.)


select o.name,
    sum(rpt.transcriptionlinecount) as 'Total Lines'
from office as o
left join RptLineCountInfo as rpt on rpt.officeID = o.officeID
where 
    rpt.finishedTime between startDate and endDate + 1
    and rpt.officeID = case when officeID is null then rpt.officeID else officeID end
    and (rpt.dictationStatus != 'd' and rpt.dictationstatus != 'q')
    and rpt.officeID != '2' or rpt.transcriptionLineCount IS NULL
group by
    o.[name]
order by
    o.[name];

Comment: By referencing the report table in the where clause you effectively turn the outer join into an inner join, for example in the line `rpt.finishedTime BETWEEN startDate AND endDate + 1` if `rpt.finishedTime` is `NULL` (as it would be if there was no match) then the predicate would not be true (since NULL = Anything evaluates to NULL), and that row excluded from the results. You should move the filter to the join clause.

Comment: This is exactly what was needed.  It is now returning all results.  Thanks!

Comment: Any suggestions on how I would add a YTD column to this existing query as well?